# Error al crear bundle en symfony 4

Tags: php, symfony4

Buenas tengo este error al ejecutar php bin/console, me arroja lo siguiente:

> In FileLoader.php line 168:
>                                                                                                        The autoloader expected class
>   "App\PruebaBundle\Controller\DefaultController" to be defined in
>   file
>   "/opt/lampp/htdocs/symfony/my-project/vendor/composer/../../src/PruebaBundle/Controller/
>   DefaultController.php". The file was found but the class was not in
>   it, the class name or name     space probably has a typo in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/symfony/my-project/config/services.yaml (which
>   is loaded in resource
>   "/opt/lampp/htdocs/symfony/my-project/config/services.yaml").
>
> In DebugClassLoader.php line 293:
>                                                                                                        The autoloader expected class
>   "App\PruebaBundle\Controller\DefaultController" to be defined in
>   file
>   "/opt/lampp/htdocs/symfony/my-project/vendor/composer/../../src/PruebaBundle/Controller/
>   DefaultController.php". The file was found but the class was not in
>   it, the class name or name     space probably has a typo.  }

Aqui mi composer.json

```
{
    "type": "project",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.0.8",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^5.1",
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "3.0",
        "symfony/asset": "^3.4",
        "symfony/console": "^3.4",
        "symfony/expression-language": "^3.4",
        "symfony/flex": "^1.0",
        "symfony/form": "^3.4",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "^3.4",
        "symfony/lts": "^3",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.1",
        "symfony/orm-pack": "*",
        "symfony/process": "^3.4",
        "symfony/security-bundle": "^3.4",
        "symfony/serializer-pack": "*",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^3.1",
        "symfony/twig-bundle": "^3.4",
        "symfony/validator": "^3.4",
        "symfony/web-link": "^3.4",
        "symfony/webpack-encore-pack": "*",
        "symfony/yaml": "^3.4"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "symfony/browser-kit": "^3.4",
        "symfony/css-selector": "^3.4",
        "symfony/debug-pack": "*",
        "symfony/dotenv": "^3.4",
        "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.0",
        "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^3.4",
        "symfony/profiler-pack": "*",
        "symfony/web-server-bundle": "^3.4"
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": {
            "*": "dist"
        },
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "replace": {
        "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php70": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php56": "*"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "auto-scripts": {
            "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
            "assets:install --symlink --relative %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd"
        },
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ]
    },
    "conflict": {
        "symfony/symfony": "*"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony": {
            "id": "01CA1B4DDM0ZQNNSBKAHV3RET0",
            "allow-contrib": false
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Prueba modificando esto:

```
"autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "": "src/"
        }
    },
```

Comment: Hola Alex, bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Recuerda leer [answer] para mejorar la calidad de tus respuetas. Lo más importante no es el codigo si no la explicacion de lo que tiene mal y cómo tu solucion lo arregla.  Añade ejemplos o documetnacion si ayuda. Un saludo.

Comment: Te recomiendo leer [Te he votado negativamente porque es solamente código.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2882/)

Comment: No es solamente codigo es cambiar la etiqueta de "autoload" por la que puse yo pensaba que con lo puesto era suficiente. Aunque ya me leere el enlace. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Symfony 4 recomienda no usar bundles para organizar el codigo (Es uno de los cambios mas importantes en esta version)

> In Symfony versions prior to 4.0, it was recommended to organize your
>   own application code using bundles. This is no longer recommended and
>   bundles should only be used to share code and features between
>   multiple applications.

https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles.html

https://symfony.es/noticias/2017/04/07/symfony-4-buenas-practicas

Slds